# How to Select textarea in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've been working on a project and had much success with selecting web elements using `.get_attribute('value')` and `.get_attribute('text')`.

I am trying to select the text from the web element in the screenshot below, but can't figure out how to select the text.

I've tried the following:

```
operation_instructions = driver.find_element_by_id('txtOperationDescription').get_attribute('value')
operation_instructions = driver.find_element_by_id('txtOperationDescription').get_attribute('text')
```

Per comments I tried the following, but they `print` a blank line:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtOperationDescription"))).get_attribute('value'))

print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtOperationDescription"))).get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Interestingly when I got `None` when trying the following:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtOperationDescription"))).get_attribute('text'))
```

Before posting the question I tried all the different elements I thought might work such as the following:

`operation_instructions = driver.find_element_by_id('txtOperationDescription').get_attribute('textarea')`

But I don't see how I can select the text in this field.

[image]

Comment: The `textarea` element should retrieve the value using `get_attribute('value')`.Have you provided enough time to load and then get the value?

Comment: Try this with explicitwait : `print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtOperationDescription"))).get_attribute('value'))`

Comment: try: get_attribute('innerHTML')

Comment: Have you tried `operation_instructions_text = driver.find_element_by_id('txtOperationDescription').text`?

Comment: @KunduK, tried your suggestions with no avail. Updated question showing that I tried.  pcalkins and Jonah, I tried your suggestions and no luck yet.

Comment: @Python_Learner_DK : Can you confirm how you are fetching this value after inserting the value in the text area field and then immediately fetching the value.

Comment: @KunduK, Not fully following your question - I am loading the page and then getting all the values from the fields.  I have all the other elements in a list and I loop through them and am able to use the `.get_attribute('value')` method successfully.  If I include `txtOperationDescription` in that loop all I get is `''` - does that answer your question?

Comment: @KunduK, to clarify, I am not pasting/inserting any values on this page, just retrieving the contents.

Comment: Well can you try this out : `print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtOperationDescription"))).get_attribute('textContent'))` OR
`print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"hndUpdateDescription"))).get_attribute('value'))` OR
`print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"hndUpdateDescription"))).get_attribute('textContent'))`

Comment: @KanduK, `.get_attribute('textContent'))` worked, thank you.  Add as an answer and I'll accept?